# Converting an Objective-C #define macro to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macros

I've got a macro in an Objective-C project that shortens typing a long reference:

```
#define CURRENT_USER DataConnector.sharedInstance.currentUser
```

This allows me to pass `CURRENT_USER` in place of ^ to reference the current user.

How would I replicate this in Swift? I've tried [this suggested `let` solution](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/01/swift-alternative-to-objective-c-macros/), but that appears actually creates a variable which is immutable. Is using `var` appropriate instead? What if the `#define` was instead:

```
#define CONST_STR = static NSString* const
```

...which can be used like:

```
CONST_STR kXXSomeConstant = @"a constant string";
```

can the Swift `let` (or `var`?) solution be used in the same fashion?

Comment: No, I'm not asking _how_ to make a constant string in Swift. Please read the question thanks.

Comment: Macros are horrible. They're not type-safe and can make debugging a nightmare. If you're really using a a particular line of code often enough to make a macro of it, you're probably doing something wrong in the first place. If I were re-writing my code in Swift, I'd be trying to find a solution that isn't a 'Swift version of a macro'.

Comment: @originaluser2 now THAT I can get behind. I agree, and I don't actually intend to use this anywhere, but I definitely want to understand if there's a way to do it in Swift, if not, and why.

Comment: using `#define` is bad practice, should be using `const` that makes it self-explanatory how to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's my understanding that the Swift compiler does not use the C preprocessor, so macros are simply not possible. Like the other commenters, I would suggest finding a more swift-like way to handle this situation. Macros have a serious down-side, as pointed out by @originaluser2 in his/her comment. (Not to mention the fatal flaw of being completely unsupported in Swift.)

Comment: Accepted, because you actually answered the question I asked ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a var with a custom getter:

```
var CURRENT_USER : User {
    return DataConnector.sharedInstance.currentUser
}
```

Comment: Right, I realize I can do that, but it's still evaluating it; the Objective-C `#define` actually creates a compiler macro that is replaced at compile-time, no?

Comment: Yes, but the overhead of a single call to this simple function (which almost certainly optimizes out to no call at all) compared to the overhead of evaluating `DataConnector.sharedInstance.currentUser` is pretty negligible.

Comment: Swift doesn't have support for preprocessor macros, in absence of those, this is pretty much the best option.

Comment: @remus: Your Objective-C macro expands to a method call every time it is used, too.

Comment: @mipadi actually it expands to two function calls `.sharedInstance` and `.currentUser`  This code potentially results in 3 functions calls, an additional call to `CURRENT_USER.get`  My guess is that in many/most cases that extra call gets omitted completely, but I haven't verified it by dumping code.

Comment: Macros are purely convenience. They are often less efficient at runtime than function calls because as David says, they just copy-paste the original code inline. Plus the total lack of type-safety and inability to debug make them painful to use (as mentioned by originaluser2.) I'm frankly glad Swift doesn't support them. Good riddance to bad rubbish, as the expression goes.